# Where is maven local repository, if the process is executed by windows SYSTEM user?

Tags: windows, maven

Jenkins service was started by windows 'SYSTEM' user and I can not find where is the actual .m2 repository to which artifacts are published from jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

Can be found at:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.m2\